# In the code specified below why do I get an Attribute Error? I am trying to create a list of all the words I scraped from a blog link

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, attributeerror

```
File "C:/Users/Souveek/PycharmProjects/WordCounter/Inventwithpythondotorg.py", line 13, in start
    words=content.lower().split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Link is http://suvrobemused.blogspot.in/2018/02/devbhoomi.html?m=1

```
def start(url):
  wordlist=[]
  source_code=requests.get(url).text
  soup=BeautifulSoup(source_code,'html.parser')
  for each_text in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'post-body entry-content'}):
     content=each_text.string
     words=content.lower().split()
     for each_word in words:
         wordlist.append(each_word)

start(link_given_above)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string):

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`

`each_text` is a `<div>` element, which (presumably) contains multiple sub-elements, so you won't get anything useful from `content=each_text.string`.  You probably want to iterate over its [`.strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) attribute instead.